# How to read data From excel sheet in iOS

Tags: ios, xcode6

I want to read data from Excel sheet to be stored in my iOS app. Does any one have idea about the function that dose that ??
thanks in advance

Comment: save as csv., read csv

Comment: How to read cvs ???? please can you help me by explaining that??

Comment: easiest way, is to probably look at an example: https://github.com/davedelong/CHCSVParser

Comment: i don't use external libraries, I don't use cocoapods, I don't use open source, but this library should be sufficient to get you started.